# which process is the initial owner of a socket, before fcntl/F_SETOWN?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

In order to catch SIGURG associated with accepted connection, one would have to do fcntl call to get the socket ownership. Does it mean that a process creating a socket is not assigned as the socket's owner by default? And, if so, who is the initial owner? Thanks

PS the question is in relation to Figure 24.11 of Network Programming by Stevens et al.

Comment: The point is that the signal isn't delivered anywhere unless a process or process group is set as the 'owner'. I agree entirely with @Casey that 'owner' is a terrible choice of words.

Comment: Then, is it specific to SIGURG? For instance, if I work with SIGALRM or SIGPIPE I do not need to set an ownership to have those signals delivered..?

Comment: Sigh. The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) says 'Set the process ID or process group ID that will receive SIGIO and SIGURG signals'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one is the initial owner. And if you set a process group ID with `F_SETOWN`, the socket goes from no "owner" to multiple "owners". The issue here is really that "owner" is a terrible choice of nomenclature, since the actual effect is more about asking for notifications of urgent data than taking ownership of the socket in some way.